# Cálculos desfases horarios en python

Tags: python

Hoy me ha surgido un problema que realmente no sé por dónde meterle mano. Espero que podáis ayudarme.
Tengo una serie de datos de los cuales me gustaría calcular el desfase de tiempo que existe entre una primera columna donde registro la aplicación de agua y la siguiente columna que recoge como sale el agua de mi sistema.

Yo entiendo que lo lógico sería crear un bucle que recorriese la primera columna hasta que cumpla la condición de que se aplique agua (en mi caso sería que fuese mayor que 0) y ver en la segunda columna a partir de ese dato cuando se registra la primera variación del flujo.

Para que sea más entendible, os pongo un ejemplo del tipo de datos que puedo tener (en imagen y en texto sin formato para que podáis disponer de dichos datos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Measurement time  Entrada     Salida
>
> 22/09/2021 7:10   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:15   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:20   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:25   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:30   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:35   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:40   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:45   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:50   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 7:55   0   1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:00   1   1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:05   83  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:10   84  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:15   84  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:20   83  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:25   83  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:30   83  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:35   80  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:40   80  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:45   82  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:50   82  1
>
> 22/09/2021 8:55   82  1
>
> 22/09/2021 9:00   82  1
>
> 22/09/2021 9:05   82  2
>
> 22/09/2021 9:10   82  3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:15   83  3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:20   82  3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:25   82  3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:30   81  3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:35   3   3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:40   0   3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:45   0   3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:50   0   3
>
> 22/09/2021 9:55   0   3

Como podréis observar, Tengo una columna como índice que es el tiempo, la columna entrada donde se ve cuando se aplica el caudal de agua y la tercera que registra el caudal de salida de agua del sistema.

Lo único que se realizar es importar los ficheros excel (que son varios) y los he unido atendiendo a la única columna en común que tienen todos, es decir, Measurement Time. Una vez aquí ya no se qué realizar o si hay alguna función que sea lo más sencillo de aplicar.

El código que pretendía utilizar es:

```
union['Diferencias salida']=abs(union['salida'].diff(1))   

for i in len(union):
    if union[i, 'entrada'] > 0:

        hora1= union[i, 'Measurement time'] for j in len(union):

    if union[j, 'Diferencias salida'] > 2:

        hora2= union[j, 'Measurement time']

   Diferenciahoras = hora2-hora1
```

Donde "union" corresponde al DataFrame que estoy utilizando y el resto de valores corresponden con las columnas del ejemplo utilizado.

¿Cómo podría realizar el bucle para que pueda obtener la información acerca del desfase entre la aplicación y la salida? ¿Alguien podría aconsejarme?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo de lo que as intentando hasta ahora?

Comment: Y podrías colocar los datos de ejemplo como texto en vez de como imagen? De ese modo podríamos usarlos para testear una posible respuesta

Comment: He editado el texto con vuestras sugerencias. Muchas gracias por vuestra pronta respuesta :D

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Para calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas con hora puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
from datetime import datetime
antes = datetime(2012, 3, 5, 23, 8, 15)        # Fecha aleatoria en el pasado
ahora  = datetime.now()                        # Fecha de este momento
diferencia = ahora - antes                     # Diferencia
diferencia_en_s = diferencia.total_seconds()   # Diferencia total en segundos
print(diferencia)                              # Diferencia en días, HH:mm:ss
```

En este ejemplo se muestra como puedes obtener la diferencia entre dos fechas con hora. Podrías cargar las fechas y hora en las variables "antes" y "ahora" al recorrer tu bucle.